# Unable to get the right output from Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, count

I have a table with field1, field2, field3, … and I need to count the number of items in field1 such that I return all records(field1,filed2,field3,…) that occur 6 times or less in the table.

My SQL code is:

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3, count(field1) CNT
FROM myTable
WHERE trunc(date)  = tp_date(‘03/22/2011’,’mm/dd/yyyy’)
GROUP BY field1
HAVING COUNT(field1)  <  7;
```

The output that I am getting from the above code is all records are returned from the table not what I expected?  Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: What do you mean by "number of items in `field1`?" Could you please post some sample data and desired output?

Comment: I need to count the contents of field1 and if there or 6 or less I need to return those record for the table.

Comment: @John: sorry, I don't understand what does "count the contents of `field1`" mean. It would be really easier if you posted sample data.

Comment: @John: just a misambiguation: If field1 appears in 7 or more rows but trunc(date)=tp_date(‘03/22/2011’,’mm/dd/yyyy’) is true for less than 7 of them, do you want these (less than 7 rows) to appear or not?

Comment: Also: if field1 appears in less than 7 rows but trunc(date)=tp_date(‘03/22/2011’,’mm/dd/yyyy’) is true for a few of them, do you want all of them to appear or not? I guess no in this case.

Comment: Asking because the 3 answers-queries have subtle differencies regarding these questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use a subquery:

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3, 
FROM myTable
WHERE trunc(date)  = tp_date(‘03/22/2011’,’mm/dd/yyyy’)
AND field1 in 
   (SELECT field1
    FROM mytable
    GROUP BY field1
    HAVING COUNT(field1)  <  7);
```

Comment: Lost in Alabama, You code is spot on!! This solved my issue and now I know to use subquery, very powerful. P.S. I am originally from Alabama but now Lost in California! Thank John

Comment: You're welcome.  Subqueries certainly can give you many more options for solving sql problems. Please mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: P.S.  Wish I lived in California too!

Comment: Sorry but this is the first time I used Stackoverflow and I do not see where to mark the answer as accepted?

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH tmp AS
(
    SELECT field1, COUNT(1) as CountOfField1
    FROM myTable
    WHERE trunc(date) = tp_date(‘03/22/2011’,’mm/dd/yyyy’)
    GROUP BY field1
    HAVING COUNT(field1) < 7
)
SELECT  mytable.field1, mytable.field2, mytable.field3, tmp.CountOfField1
FROM    myTable 
        INNER JOIN tmp 
            ON myTable.Field1 = tmp.Field1
```

Comment: Clyc, Thanks you for your example! I will code this up to see how this works!

Comment: You don't need the `<7` check twice.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way to do it:

```
SELECT t.field1, t.field2, t.field3, 
FROM myTable t
WHERE trunc(t.date) = tp_date(‘03/22/2011’,’mm/dd/yyyy’)
  AND EXISTS
  ( SELECT *
    FROM mytable t2
    WHERE t2.field1 = t.field1
      AND trunc(t2.date) = tp_date(‘03/22/2011’,’mm/dd/yyyy’)
    GROUP BY t2.field1
    HAVING COUNT(t2.field1)  <  7
  )
;
```